# EntityType has no key defined on postgres stored function call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql, entity-framework

how to get rid of this error.

> EntityType 'String_concept_attributesModel' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

Im trying to call function from Postgres database on .net mvc controller and it should return result as Json data type.

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ajaxmethod(string test)
    {
        if (test == null)
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                msg = "there is no string",
                id = 0,
                destination = 000000,
                hierarchy = 00000
            });
        }
        using (var db = new PGDbContext())
        {
            var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "public.kp_string_to_concept_attributes";

            try
            {
               db.Database.Connection.Open();
               var source = new SqlParameter("@source_string", test);

                var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<String_concept_attributesModel>("public.kp_string_to_concept_attributes @source_string", source).ToList();

                if(!result.Any())
                {
                    return Json(new
                    {
                        msg = "Empty list",
                        id = 00000,
                        destination = 000000,
                        hierarchy = 00000
                    });
                }

                return Json(new
                {
                    msg = "all done",
                    id = result.First().concept_id,
                    destination = result.First().attribute_id,
                    hierarchy = result.First().description_id
                });
            }
            finally
            {
                db.Database.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

And my Entity looks like :

```
 public class String_concept_attributesModel
{

    public Int64 description_id { get; set; }
    public Int64 concept_id { get; set; }
    public string concept_text { get; set; }
    public string concept_bits { get; set; }
    public Int64 attribute_id { get; set; }
    public string attribute_text { get; set; }
    public Int64 value_id { get; set; }
    public string value_text { get; set; }
    public string value_bits { get; set; }
}
```

And I cannot put key on top of some line, because all of those aren't unique. 
So how to define the key in this reason?
PS. connection between entity framework and postgresql was made by using "Code First from database" - so I dont have any of those edmx files.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice always to have a primary key.  Add a field public string ID {get; set;}
to String_concept_attributesModel and to the DB and make it auto incremented.  This should solve the problem. (Since it is called 'id', entity framework will know that it's supposed to be the primary key, so you don't have to use [Key])